# Ubuntu / Windows dual boot : How to solve "read-only" issue when trying to write on a NTFS mounted volume?

Tags: ubuntu, browser, permissions, ntfs

### EDIT :

This was originally a question about why I couldn't download anything to my displaced Downloads folder. The issue solved itself after rebooting the computer a second time (no idea why). I decided to leave it here anyway since it contains useful information to people who want to redirect their files on a mounted volume.

### EDIT 2 :

I was right at first, there was indeed an issue with my dual boot. The problem was that sometimes, I couldn't write anything on my NTFS partition when I was booted on Ubuntu. The reason for that was that Windows hadn't properly disconnected from the partition. More info about that issue [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70281/why-does-my-ntfs-partition-mount-as-read-only), but basically it happens when Windows isn't completely turned off before Ubuntu starts. The quick fix is to remove the Windows log file : `$ sudo ntfsfix /dev/your-NTFS-partition` (for me it was : `$ sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda4`). Then you simply unmount and remount the NTFS volume and you should be able to write in it, no reboot needed.

#### Context :

I made my first dual boot yesterday, following [this tutorial](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/35807/how-to-harmonize-your-dual-boot-setup-for-windows-and-ubuntu/). I partitioned my drive in 3 volumes, 1 for Windows 10, 1 for Ubuntu 20.04, and 1 for my files (named Storage), that I mounted at /media/storage. The only thing that I did differently from the walkthrough is that I used symlinks to redirect my downloads and documents folders to the mounted volume instead of changing the paths in /etc/fstab. I used [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CsdTwW2P8V0) to learn how to work with symlinks.

I had an issue with the Trash not working in the mounted volume, that I solved by adding uid=1000 in the mount options in /etc/fstab as advised [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75154/cannot-move-file-to-trash-warning-when-trying-to-delete-a-file-in-nautilus) (I used udisks). Everything seemed to be working just fine after that.

#### Issue :

This morning I tried to download a file with Google Chrome into the Downloads folder (which is now at /media/storage/Downloads) and I got an error "Failed - insufficient permissions". Same thing happened with Firefox. Both browsers download without issue if I use my home folder to save the file.

[image: Download failed]

I read [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2377758) that :

> As a normal user you don't have the right to write anywhere except your home directory and
> its subdirectories, /tmp (the directory for temporary files) and the
> subdirectories of /media/"yourUsername" into which media you've
> connected to the computer are mounted.

Does this mean that I should have mounted my volume at /media/username/storage instead of /media/storage ? If I changed the mount path now in /etc/fstab, would this fix the issue or just mess everything up? Is there something else I'm missing ? What is the best, most sustainable way to fix this ?

#### More info (more issues) ?

I just realized that I have some lock icons on my symlinks folders. They can't have been there yesterday, because everytime I try to modify anything in there, the system throws an error "Read-only file system". I know that I was able to add and delete files from there yesterday.

[image: Read-only file system]

Here is the output of `/media/storage$ ls -l` :

```
total 4
drwxrwxrwx 1 val root    0 Mar 12 14:14 '$RECYCLE.BIN'
drwxrwxrwx 1 val root    0 Mar 18 18:14  Backup
drwxrwxrwx 1 val root    0 Mar 18 20:13  Documents
drwxrwxrwx 1 val root 4096 Mar 18 20:14  Downloads
drwxrwxrwx 1 val root    0 Mar 18 20:15  Music
drwxrwxrwx 1 val root    0 Mar 18 20:14  Pictures
drwxrwxrwx 1 val root    0 Mar 18 16:23  Public
drwxrwxrwx 1 val root    0 Mar 12 14:45 'System Volume Information'
drwxrwxrwx 1 val root    0 Mar 18 16:23  Templates
drwxrwxrwx 1 val root    0 Mar 18 20:16  Videos
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No idea how or why, but the good old "turn it off and on again" did the trick (EDIT : No it didn't, see EDIT 2 of my question). Why did it not work when I rebooted my computer earlier today ? Mystery. Anyway I will leave this here (and edit the title) since it is a good collection of the issues I had while working out my first dual boot and the methods I used to fix them.

Comment: Glad that you solved your issue! Just FYI though - Stack Overflow is for programming-related questions. General computing questions belong on SuperUser.

Comment: The site is moderated by the Community, based on published guidelines. Whether someone upvotes or downvotes, there's really no way to control that. But honestly, calling someone a random "keyboard warrior" isn't the nicest thing to say, especially when people are empowered and encouraged to ask, answer, comment, vote, flag, etc.